# How to scale tab images in high DPI 4k Windows Form application?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, highdpi

In my Windows Form application I use images from an image list for my tabs. This is configured via Visual Studio 2022, no code written on my side.

Looks fine on a 1920 resolution.

[image: 1920 res]

However, under 4k the images appear rather small.
Any chance to adjust this?

[image: 4k]

The image list has a setting for the `ImageSize` of `16,16`. If I increase it to `32,32` it appears correct under 4k, but oversized at 1920.

I did try to just change the size at runtime like below, but this leads to no images at all.

```
int dpiFactor = (int)(this.DeviceDpi / 96.0);
if (dpiFactor >= 2)
{
    Size imageSize = il_Application.ImageSize;
    imageSize.Width *= dpiFactor;
    imageSize.Height *= dpiFactor;
    il_Application.ImageSize = imageSize;
}
```

The auto-generated code does not contain the size at all, so I assume the scaling takes place at generation time.

```
il_Application.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth8Bit;
il_Application.ImageStream = (ImageListStreamer)resources.GetObject("il_Application.ImageStream");
il_Application.Tag = "application icons";
il_Application.TransparentColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Is there a setting to get it automatically scaled like the rest of the application?

[image: Image list]

Comment: Is your application DpiAware? Otherwise `DeviceDpi / 96.0` is always `1`. But it's also `1` when the DPI is less than `192`, which is quite probable -- You can load the images  and set the size, on the fly, after the Form has created its Handle -- *The auto-generated code does not contain the size at all*: the default, if not otherwise specified, is `16x16` -- For *compatibility reasons*, the `ColorDepth` should be set to `Depth32Bit` -- When you change the ImageSize or ColorDepth, the Handle of the ImageList is recreated. Any image already added is deleted

Comment: I get a `DeviceDpi` ratio of 1 (1920) and 2.5 (4k). I assume the autogenerated code contains the data "hardcoded" in the resources. So what I have done is to create 2 image lists (16x16/32x32) and simply switch the list in the tab control and runtime (one-liner).

But it is probably better to copy the images to the resource directory and load the images in my own code.

Thanks for the feedback.